# Citation de l'Académie Française sur l'orthographe

Tags: orthographe, histoire, académie-française

Dans une conférence TED (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5YO7Vg1ByA8), j'ai entendu une citation qui viendrait des cahiers préparatoires au premier dictionnaire de l'Académie Française, et qui serait la suivante.

> L’orthographe servira à distinguer les gens de lettres d’avec les ignorants et les simples femmes.

Il semblerait que cette citation date de 1696 (https://etincelle.blog/2019/07/26/pourquoi-le-francais-est-il-si-difficile/). Or je n'ai rien pu trouver de plus précis sur celle-ci.

Est-elle authentique ou apocryphe ? Sauriez-vous où on peut la trouver, plus précisément ? Merci !

Comment: Cette phrase m'a l'air très anachronique pour 1996

Comment: Oups, c'est une faute de frappe de ma part, je voulais dire 1696, au temps pour moi ! ^^

Comment: La préface de la première édition date de 1694 et est accessible sur le site de l'Académie française. On n'y trouve pas cette phrase. Si cette phrase n'est pas inventée, il serait logique qu'elle ait été écrite avant.

Comment: Effectivement, ça fait sens... Ce serait donc soit une invention (quand bien même cela semble cohérent avec les connaissances linguistiques et sociologiques sur l'époque, peut-être serait-ce alors un raccourci), soit une erreur du blog "étincelle"...

Comment: « Faire sens » n'est pas considéré comme du français correct : https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/faire-sens/ , http://www.academie-francaise.fr/faire

Comment: Je  trouve la  confirmation du fait que je suspecte « faire sens » être un anglicisme dans le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_sens) ; cependant ce dictionnaire reconnait cette forme ; mais je crois que les justifications que l'on apporte à cette expression, telles qu'issues de la langue plus ancienne et de la philosophie pourraient ne pas être celle que l'on donne à cette expression dans le français d'aujourd'hui et qui n'est rien d'autre que celle donnée en anglais (**avoir** du sens). « Faire sens »aurait pu signifier « contribuer à un sens » Wik: faire sens avec qch.

Comment: @LPH: Néanmoins on continuera à l'utiliser, n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: @HarryAudus Je n'en ai pas la moindre idée, du pile ou face ; il y a bien une tendance vers l'élimination des conceptions qui n'ont pas une base saine mais ce n'est qu'une tendance, il n'y a pas de critère vraiment solide; nombreuses sont les expressions dont la logique est scabreuse mais qui sont restées dans le vocabulaire en dépit de ça. À mon avis celle-ci ne mérite pas de faire partie du français. Mis à part la phonétique légèrement embêtante dans une combinaison comme « ça a du sens » la traduction « avoir du sens » est idéale parce que fidèle à l'anglais (1/2)

Comment: @HarryAudus et alignée sur le principe de compositionalité. De plus c'est une traduction qui n'empiète pas sur la forme déjà existante « faire sens ». Mais cette possibilité n'est due qu'à mes déductions personnelles; je ne crois pas qu'elle ait été discutée ailleurs: ce qui a été envisagé, par l'Ac. si je ne me trompe, c'est de traduire l'anglais « make sense » par « prendre sens », ce qui à mon avis ne convient pas, à plus d'un point de vue. (2/2)

Comment: @LPH : Selon Wiktionnaire, « Il s’agit d’un terme utilisé qui n’est pas d’un usage standard.[1] Absente du Petit Robert, du Larousse et du TLFi, condamnée par l’Académie française, cette expression est néanmoins parfois utilisée en philosophie et en études littéraires. » J'ai voulu dire simplement que, quoi qu'en dise l'Académie, les gens qui veulent utiliser l'expression le feront.

Comment: @HarryAudus Oh oui, très vrai ! Les avis de l'Académie ne font pas autorité de nos jours… C'est une criante anomalie dans le système mais ce qui ne marche pas n'est pas clair ; la raison est vraisemblablement la combinaison moderne de l'accessibilité des masses à l'éducation avec un abaissement du niveau de cette éducation. (Les masses populaires qui ne semblent plus attachées à aucune institution et ne semblent être liées entre elles par aucun lien de société permanente (Maine de Biran, Journal, 1821, p.311).

Comment: @LPH : Je ne pense pas que l'évolution du langage, à quelque époque que ce soit, ait suivi les diktats d'un corps autoritaire. Le langage évolue de manière indépendante, et la plupart des linguistes et lexicographes d'aujourd'hui acceptent une approche descriptive plutôt que prescriptive. Mais cette page n'est pas le bon endroit pour relancer une guerre entre les prescripteurs et les descripteurs.

Comment: @HarryAudus Nous sommes loin d'avoir à penser à imposer un point de vue par la "guerre" ; il n'est question pour l'instant que de faits. Il est bien possible, comme vous le croyez,  que dans les siècles passés 'lAc. n'ait pas eu toute l'autorité que je tend à lui prêter en matière de langage ; il faudrait s'en remettre à des études spécifiques de ce sujet,  et je n'ai jamais eu le loisir de me consacrer à ça.

Comment: Je penserais que l'Académie devienne de nos jours même moins important. Google Ngram peut être utilisé pour donner une idée raisonnablement précise de l'usage linguistique réel, par opposition à l'usage linguistique prescrit, du mot écrit. L'évaluation de la façon dont les gens utilisent les mots parlés nécessite des sondages approfondis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D'après le grammairien [Charles Marty-Laveaux](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Marty-Laveaux) dans *[L'ami de la religion: journal ecclésiastique, politique et littéraire](https://books.google.fr/books?id=0SoBAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr#v=onepage&q&f=false)*, Volume 5, p 529 et suivantes, 1860, cette phrase a été écrite entre le 14 août et le 12 octobre 1673 par [M de Mezeray](https://data.bnf.fr/fr/12301056/francois_eudes_de_mezeray/) dans un manuscrit inédit et jamais cité jusqu'alors conservé à la Bibliothèque impériale intitulé *Résolutions de l'Académie françoise touchant l'orthographe prises sur les propositions et recherches de Monsieur de Mezeray* puis renommé *Cahiers de remarques sur l'orthographe françoise pour estre examinez par chacun des Messieurs de l'Académie*.

> La compagnie déclare qu'elle désire suivre l'ancienne orthographe, qui distingue les gens de lettres d'avec les ignorants et les simples femmes, et qu'il faut la maintenir partout, hormis dans les mots où un long et constant usage en aura introduit une contraire.

Un fac-simile de l'original est consultable à la BNF mais ne semble pas téléchargeable.

https://catalogue.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/cb33275895h

https://catalogue.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/cb37380875m

Ambroise Firmin Didot cite ce passage mais sans mentionner les *faibles femmes* dans *Observations sur l'orthographe ou ortografie française*, 1868.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour toutes ces précisions !

Answer (score 1):

Cette citation est due à  Eudes de Mézeray, qui a été admis à l'Académie en 1673. ([réf.](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/lorthographe-histoire-dune-longue-querelle)).

> Pour Mézeray, l’Académie doit préférer « l’ancienne orthographe, qui distingue les gens de Lettres d’avec les Ignorants et les simples femmes ». Avec cette formule de Mézeray, l’Académie définit alors une position qui sera le point de départ d’une durable accusation de « conservatisme ».

Comme il est mort en [1683](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eudes_de_M%C3%A9zeray), il n'a pas pu prononcer ces mot en 1696, mais ils seraient bien dus à lui et la citation n'est pas de l'invention.

Comment: Merci pour ce complément d'information !